# Is there a way to communicate with Google API without using the API key?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7, google-calendar-api

I have a very simple app which I copied from https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/instantiate and have pasted it below:

```
import gflags
import httplib2

from apiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.file import Storage
from oauth2client.client import OAuth2WebServerFlow
from oauth2client.tools import run

FLAGS = gflags.FLAGS

# Set up a Flow object to be used if we need to authenticate. This
# sample uses OAuth 2.0, and we set up the OAuth2WebServerFlow with
# the information it needs to authenticate. Note that it is called
# the Web Server Flow, but it can also handle the flow for native
# applications
# The client_id and client_secret can be found in Google Developers Console
FLOW = OAuth2WebServerFlow(
    client_id='YOUR_CLIENT_ID',
    client_secret='YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET',
    scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar',
    user_agent='YOUR_APPLICATION_NAME/YOUR_APPLICATION_VERSION')

# To disable the local server feature, uncomment the following line:
# FLAGS.auth_local_webserver = False

# If the Credentials don't exist or are invalid, run through the native client
# flow. The Storage object will ensure that if successful the good
# Credentials will get written back to a file.
storage = Storage('calendar.dat')
credentials = storage.get()
if credentials is None or credentials.invalid == True:
  credentials = run(FLOW, storage)

# Create an httplib2.Http object to handle our HTTP requests and authorize it
# with our good Credentials.
http = httplib2.Http()
http = credentials.authorize(http)

# Build a service object for interacting with the API. Visit
# the Google Developers Console
# to get a developerKey for your own application.
service = build(serviceName='calendar', version='v3', http=http,
       developerKey='YOUR_DEVELOPER_KEY')
```

I then added the following code to access the Google calendar api (copied from https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list):

```
page_token = None
while True:
  events = service.events().list(calendarId='primary', pageToken=page_token).execute()
  for event in events['items']:
    print event['summary']
  page_token = events.get('nextPageToken')
  if not page_token:
    break
```

There are however two ip addresses that I need to provide in the Google developer's console to get the service to work; namely the my LAN ip (e.g. 192.168.1.111) and my current IPv4 address (which I get by searching `What is my IP address?` on Google). The problem is, my ISP constantly changes the IP address assigned to me. Hence to get my test app to work, I have to go to Google developer's console, and there in `My Project>>APIs & Auth>>Credentials>>Public API access` I have to modify the list of allowed IPs. For convenience I have made my LAN ip static. However I have no control over what IP address my ISP assigns me. How do I configure a service which uses my laptop as the server and is able to authenticate itself with the changing IP addresses?

Comment: No you cant access any of the Google APIs with out registering your application.   I don't know enough about python to help but I would be surprised you cant set it to localhost like you can with php for testing.

Answer (score 0):

Not only does it let you enter an IP address, but also you can enter subnets.  Your ISP will assign your public address from a pool, and you can type that pool into the developer console.

For example, Ford Motor Company has IP address 19.0.0.1, but actually it has more than that, it has the entire range 19.0.0.0/8, in other words 19.0.0.0 through 19.255.255.255.

You can enter 19.0.0.1 into the list of allowed addresses, or you can enter 19.0.0.0/8 for the entire range.

Your broadband modem or gateway is most likely getting a DHCP lease from your ISP.  The DHCP lease includes netmask information.  From the netmask information, you can derive your subnet.

http://www.aelius.com/njh/subnet_sheet.html